# Linux Device Driver: pass flags to driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I need to know if there is a way to pass information to my character driver. My driver needs to set flags in registers and I am not sure how to pass them in. I basically want the user to be able to set these flags prior to sending data to the character driver.

I am not trying to pass arguments on each driver init (insmod).

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You may use ioctl() for sending flags for this character device.

Comment: Ok I'll look into implementing it. 

For test purposes, is there a way to call ioctl from the command line similar to a .write or .read method? 

I'm fairly new to character drivers and I'm not sure how certain methods are called. Similarly if you could explain how .probe gets called.

For ioctl I am looking at 
http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x892.html

Thanks!
Kevin